# how to set height constraint in IBDesignable file?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I need to make an IBDesignable to make a custom navigation bar file that will adjust the height of the view based on the iPhone type. if the iPhone has top notch like iPhone X,XR, then the height contraint will be 88, otherwise for iPhone 8 that does not has top notch, the height will be 64.

I need to set the height contraint, not the layer height. here is the code I use but it fails to update the height contraint

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomParentNavigationBarView: UIView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setHeight()
    }


    func setHeight() {
        let deviceHasTopNotch = checkHasTopNotchOrNot()
        var heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()

        if deviceHasTopNotch {

            heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 88)

        } else {

            heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 64)

        }

        heightConstraint.isActive = true
        self.addConstraint(heightConstraint)


    }

    func checkHasTopNotchOrNot() -> Bool {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, tvOS 11.0, *) {
            // with notch: 44.0 on iPhone X, XS, XS Max, XR.
            // without notch: 20.0 on iPhone 8 on iOS 12+.
            return UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0 > 20
        }
        return false
    }





}
```

the result should be something like this (red view), the height of the red view should change according to iPhone type, either 88 or 64
[image]

for the initial value, I set the autolayout of the view in storyboard like this

[image]

Comment: `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`?

Comment: I don't have that code

Comment: Try adding that.

Comment: where do I have to put translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false? in awakefromNib?

Comment: If you are using storboard, it should be available there as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems that I can see.

1. You are not activating the constraints. Add this line
   `heightConstraint.isActive = true`
2. You are calling SetHeight multiple times. Each time, a constraint is added. This will lead to constraint conflicts and poor behavior. Instead, just create the constraint once and store it as a member.

Comment: i have edit my code above, I have added heightConstraint.isActive = true and only implement setHeight once, but the height still the same, am I edit the code right ?

Comment: Are you sure that awakeFromNib is called and setHeight is called?

Comment: yes sir, the code above is exactly the same as my IBDesignable file. then I assign that CustomParentNavigationBarView in the desired view in storyboard

Comment: Are you using constraints for this view in your storyboard?

Comment: if not you will need to add constraints for leading, trailing, and top. Either programmatically or in the storyboard. If you do this programmatically you will also need translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: I set the leading, trailing and top contraints in storyboards ( I have added the picture above), and the height of the view initially set to 64 in storyboard (is this the problem?).

Comment: You need to delete your height constraint in storyboard. That will definitely cause a conflict. You may also need to delete your bottom space constraints; depending on your label and button constraints this may also cause a conflict.

Comment: Woohoo! I'm glad I could help :)